# Complex Object losing data

Tags: java, trie

I know references to objects in java are passed by copy , but the copy still points to the same memory in system , so after updating some data of the complex object in another function , the original data should me maintained. But interestingly something is going wrong here. I am working with Tries.

Here is my implementation of Trie, it's fairly custom implementation because of some custom rules:

```
public class Trie {
    boolean isEnd;
    Trie trie[] = new Trie[256];
    ArrayList<Integer> indexNode;

    public static Trie createTrieNode() {
        Trie temp = new Trie();
        temp.isEnd = false;
        temp.indexNode = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.trie.length; i++) {
            temp.trie[i] = null;
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public static void insertIntoTrie(Trie root, char[] alpha, int index, int i) {
        if (root == null)
            root = createTrieNode();
        if (i < alpha.length)
            insertIntoTrie(root.trie[alpha[i] - 'a'], alpha, index, i + 1);
        else {
            if (root.isEnd == true) {
                root.indexNode.add(index);
            } else {
                root.isEnd = true;
                root.indexNode.add(index);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Now my object `root` comes from this class and In the debugger I can see this statement being executed : `root.isEnd = true;`

Class:

```
 public class AnagramsTogether {
        public Trie root = new Trie();
        public void printAnagrams(String[] anagrams){
            char[] buffer;
            for (int i = 0; i < anagrams.length; i++) {
                buffer = anagrams[i].toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(buffer);
              Trie.insertIntoTrie(root, buffer, i, 0);
            }
            AnagramsUtil.anagramUtil(root,anagrams);
        }
  }
```

But when when `root` is passed here `AnagramsUtil.anagramUtil(root,anagrams);`

```
public class AnagramsUtil {

    public static void anagramUtil(Trie root, String[] anagrams) {

        if (root.isEnd == true) {

            for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = root.indexNode.iterator(); iterator
                    .hasNext();) {
                Integer integer = (Integer) iterator.next();
                System.out.println(anagrams[integer]);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < root.trie.length; i++) {
                if (root.trie[i] == null)
                    continue;
                anagramUtil(root.trie[i], anagrams);
            }
        }
    }

}
public class Anagram{
                   public static String string[] = {"cat", "dog", "god","act", "tac","gdo"};
                   public static void main(String args){
                      new AnagramsTogether().printAnagrams(Anagram.string); 
                 }
}
```

This statement `if (root.isEnd == true)` in never executed and so is this is never executed  `anagramUtil(root.trie[i], anagrams);` . The program just keep executing the `continue` statement.
Which should not be the case as I've already seen `root.trie[i]`  receiving values.
Why does this happen?I am fairly new to java.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/645270) could help

Comment: What arguments are you using when calling `printAnagrams(String[] anagrams)`?

Comment: edited my code with the argument.

Comment: @ArjunVerma you can't create a new object using `if (root == null) root = createTrieNode();`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You have many `Trie` objects in your program and you are confusing them.  If you check object identity (object number) with your debugger, you will see that they are not the same.

Comment: Yes I did see the id's were not same. Why did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you see in the debugger the statement `root.isEnd = true;` to be executed however you don't mention for *which object* is executing.

Your `insertIntoTrie()` method is called *recursively* so, that statement is probably executed for the `Trie` objects that the `root` has in its `trie[]` array but not for the `root` object itself.

Since the actual execution depends on the arguments you are using to call `printAnagrams(String[] anagrams)` please add those to your question if you need a more specific answer.

**Update:** Ok after you have edited your question it is clear that you are making the mistake to misuse object references even though you know that all  *"...references to objects in java are passed by copy"*. Your `insertIntoTrie()` is faulty. It seems that you intend to create a new object if the argument `root` is `null` however that new object will be lost because `root` argument ***is a copy***. At the end of your method if you print the whole `trie[]` member of your original `root` object (the one in the `AnagramsTogether` class) you will see that all objects are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `null` is not an object, it is only a special type. Therefore `null` hasn't got a reference. So that, for example:

```
Trie root = null;
insertIntoTrie(root, alpha, index, i); 
// after called this function, root = null
```

After called this function, `root` is still `null` because the variable `root` isn't yet an object before calling this function. So that there wasn't any reference of the variable `root` to be passed by copy in this calling.

**Solution**:

Change your function:

```
 public static void insertIntoTrie(Trie root, char[] alpha, int index, int i) {
    if (root == null)
        root = createTrieNode();
    if (i < alpha.length)
        insertIntoTrie(root.trie[alpha[i] - 'a'], alpha, index, i + 1);
    else {
        if (root.isEnd == true) {
            root.indexNode.add(index);
        } else {
            root.isEnd = true;
            root.indexNode.add(index);
        }
    }

}
```

Into :

```
public static void insertIntoTrie(Trie root, char[] alpha, int index, int i) {
    if (i < alpha.length) {
        if (root.trie[alpha[i] - 'a'] == null) {
            root.trie[alpha[i] - 'a'] = createTrieNode();
        }
        insertIntoTrie(root.trie[alpha[i] - 'a'], alpha, index, i + 1);
    }
    else {
        if (root.isEnd == true) {
            root.indexNode.add(index);
        } else {
            root.isEnd = true;
            root.indexNode.add(index);
        }
    }

}
```

This solution make sure that the `root` is always an object before passing to the `insertIntoTrie(...)` function.